# Configuring Single Kibana server for multiple Elastic search clusters

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, kibana

Can I know how to configure Kibana 5.6.2 for multiple Elastic search clusters..? I have two Different Elastic search clusters, one for metadata and another for analytics ..? So I Just want to use same Kibana 5.6.2 server for monitoring both the cluster's..?
Please help guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a Tribe node.

You can find more information about configuring a tribe node here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-tribe.html

The tribe node will allow you to query data from both clusters.

In your `kibana.yml`:

```
elasticsearch.url: http://my_kibana_cluster:9200
elasticsearch.tribe.url: http://my_tribe_node:9200
```

`http://my_kibana_cluster:9200` will need to be a non-tribe cluster which will be used to persist the `.kibana` index.

Here is additional information on using tribe with Kibana: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tribe.html